# Powershell tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I reccomed a synonyms for the Tags `Powershell` and `Powershell-v2.0`.

Formerly people speak about the first version of Powershell like Porwershell and about the second version like Powershell v2.

But now when we speak about the second version of Powershell we simply says Powershell. In fact no many people knows about that this is the second version.

So I recommend to create a synonymous from `Powershell-v2.0` to `Powershell` or rename all the Powershell tag to `Powerhsell-v1.0`.
¿What do you think?

Comment: We don't like version tags unelss they're critical to the process (so, apache-1 and apache-2 are different, but apache-2 and apache-2.1 are synonymed). How much difference is there between v1 and v2?

Comment: @Mark Not too much. V1 was the version included on Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 and v2 is the version included on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 32. But in general the scripts are the same.

I think we shouldn't specify the version of Powershell in a tag. Or if we are doing to do that change the name of Powershell to Powershell-v2 to be clear.

Answer (score 2):

They added a bunch off cmdlets in v2 so not all v2-script will run on v1.
More info: [Clickity Clackety](http://www.nivot.org/post/2009/02/04/DifferencesBetweenPowerShell10RTMAndPowershell20CTP3Win7Beta.aspx)

I think however most people that are talking about [powershell](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/powershell) actually mean [powershell-v2.0](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/powershell-v2.0) so a synonym would be in place here.

Edit: Looks like I'm late to the party since it looks it's already in place.

Comment: Well, then we should reaname the "powershell" tag to "powershell-v1.0"

Answer (score 0):

How does stack overflow handle the problems of versions? Do they have specific tags for python-2.6 python-3.0? Looks like they do: `python` and `python-3.x`.

I have a feeling this issue will continue as powershell versions increment. We will probably need to revist this subject about the time powershell 4 is released (but that might be years from now).